# Freeware xslt debugger software

Tags: xml, xslt

I need a freeware software on which I can run xpath queries and also can make xslt debug(see values of variables etc..).I am rarely using xml tools, and now i have EditX but its xslt debugger feature is not free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XSLT Project from Eclipse - http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project

Personally, I have found oXygen XML to be very good - http://www.oxygenxml.com/, it has helped me a lot and if you are a student/academic, the price is worth it.